# Pandas max value index

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, indexing, max

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a mix of screen names, tweets, fav's etc.  I want find the max value of 'favcount' (which i have already done) and also return the screen name of that 'tweet'

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['timestamp'] = timestamp
df['sn'] = sn
df['text'] = text
df['favcount'] = fav_count


print df
print '------'
print df['favcount'].max()
```

I cant seem to find anything on this, can anyone help guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use <s>`argmax()`</s> `idxmax()`  to get the index of the max value. Then you can use `loc`

```
df.loc[df['favcount'].idxmax(), 'sn']
```

*Edit:* `argmax()` *is now deprecated, switching for* `idxmax()`

Comment: if your column contains only nan values, this will result in TypeError

Answer (score 21):

I think you need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) - get index of max value of `favcount` and then select value in column `sn` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'favcount':[1,2,3], 'sn':['a','b','c']})

print (df)
   favcount sn
0         1  a
1         2  b
2         3  c

print (df.favcount.idxmax())
2

print (df.loc[df.favcount.idxmax()])
favcount    3
sn          c
Name: 2, dtype: object

print (df.loc[df.favcount.idxmax(), 'sn'])
c
```

Answer (score 0):

By using same df as above,

```
# python code
df = pd.DataFrame({'favcount':[1,2,3], 'sn':['a','b','c']})
print (df)
favcount sn
0         1  a
1         2  b
2         3  c
## You can use max()
print(df[df.favcount.max() == df['favcount']])
favcount sn
2         3  c
## If you need specific column you can select it
print(df[df.favcount.max() == df['favcount']].sn)
2    c
```