# How to isolate the maximum value in a data frame in pandas python library

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to isolate and print the maximum value in a pandas dataframe in python.

```
# Data frame:

df
>>     0   A   B   C
    0  0   0   0   0
    A  0  -3  -3   5
    B  0  -3  -6   2
    C  0   5   0  -3
    D  0   5   2  -3
    E  0   0  10   5
    F  0  -3   5  15
```

I have managed to isolate the value with the following code:

```
x = df.max(axis=0)
maxValue = max(x)

maxValue
>> 15
```

But how can I access this element? Is there a way to iterate through the elements of the data frame such that

```
for elements in df:
    if element == maxValue:
        m = element
```

Or something on those lines? I need to find the largest element, in this case 15, and retrieve its position i.e. (C,F) in this example. I then need to store this and then find the next largest element surrounding the first, along with its position.

```
# desired output
[(C,F), (B,E), (A,D)]
```

I hope this makes sense! Any advice on how I could implement this would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas max value index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964558/pandas-max-value-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#replace 'df.iloc[:,1:]' with 'df' if first column isnt 0
out = [*df.iloc[:,1:][::-1].idxmax().items()] 
#[('A', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'F')]
```

Comment: I tried this and I got a TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype ?

Comment: @CharlieVagg can you try `[*df.iloc[:,1:][::-1].astype(float).idxmax().items()]` ?

Comment: I got this as an output: [<itertools.izip object at 0x7f5ef0b76c80>]

Comment: @CharlieVagg works fine for me, may be some version issues not sure try `list(df.iloc[:,1:][::-1].astype(float).idxmax().items())` but really works if you test with the sample data if all columns are numeric

Comment: ah I was using python 2 instead of 3, it has worked now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I understand question is necessary sorting maximal values, so use if nedd omit first column [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) for positions of maximums with `max` for maximums, sorting them by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), select it to `Series` and last convert to list of tuples:

```
L = (list(df.iloc[:, 1:]
            .agg(['idxmax','max'])
            .sort_values('max', axis=1, ascending=False)
            .loc['idxmax'].items()))
print (L)
[('C', 'F'), ('B', 'E'), ('A', 'C')]
```

For all columns remove `iloc`:

```
L = (list(df.agg(['idxmax','max'])
            .sort_values('max', axis=1, ascending=False)
            .loc['idxmax'].items()))
print (L)
[('C', 'F'), ('B', 'E'), ('A', 'C'), ('0', '0')]
```

Comment: I get a KeyError: 'idxmax'. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @CharlieVagg - Yes, data are not numeric. Try `L = (list(df.select_dtypes(np.number).agg(['idxmax','max'])
            .sort_values('max', axis=1, ascending=False)
            .loc['idxmax'].items()))
print (L)`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `sort_values` + `stack`

```
df.stack().sort_values().groupby(level=1).tail(1).index.tolist()
Out[229]: [('A', '0'), ('D', 'A'), ('E', 'B'), ('F', 'C')]
```