# How to find max value and coinciding day in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I am trying to create a point that will show the maximum value in a dataset and what day it occurs on. My data set has been read in as a pandas data frame and I used df.max() to get the max value in the date range specified. However, so that I can further analyze the data set, I would like to know what date this point occurred on. Is there an additional function I can call that will couple the date with the value?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to index into your data frame by the index where the maximum occurs and pull out your date value...break this into pieces and I guarantee you'll find your answer on this site already. :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964614/12337195
You can use `idxmax()` to get the index of the maximum value, which you can then use to access your coinciding day at the maximum value

Comment: This one worked for me thank you!

Comment: You should flag this as a duplicate, then, no?

Comment: @AMC already did, but actually giving the answer is nicer than just saying it's a duplicate